# Procedures in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I don't understand how to use the procedures in the table and why we use procedures in PL/SQL? Moreover, please provide me at least on example if possible. I also have a confusion in the syntax specially in the declaration part. Either we declare in IS part or before to that.

I want to know why we use procedures in PL/SQL as well as syntax for it? Explain with at least one example.

Answer (score 1):

We don't use procedures in tables; what did you want to say with that?

Procedures usually contain group of (PL/)SQL statements which are supposed to perform certain task. For example, there's department with several employees  whose data has to be updated throughout number of tables - as long as you can do that in series of separate SQL statements (SELECT something, UPDATE something else, INSERT into somewhere, DELETE from some table), that becomes tedious as you have to repeat it. Therefore, create a procedure that accepts department ID as parameter and let the procedure do that job in a loop.

As of declaration part: syntax says it all, you just have to follow it.

Example you asked for; not very *smart*, though, just for *illustration* purposes:

```
create or replace procedure p_update_employees (par_dept_id in dept.dept_id%type) 
is
  l_cnt number;            --> this is declaration part
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from employees
    where dept_id = par_dept_id;

  if l_cnt > 0 then
     for cur_r in (select emp_id from employees
                   where dept_id = par_dept_id) loop
       insert into archive_emp (emp_id, dept_id, salary)
         select emp_id, dept_id, salary
         from employees
         where emp_id = cur_r.emp_id;

       update jobs set
         active = 'NO'
         where emp_id = cur_r.emp_id;

       delete from tasks
         where emp_id = cur_r.emp_id;
     end loop;
  end if;
end;
/
```

---

I'd suggest you to visit this (old) [Oracle 10g documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/index.htm) page. It contains groups of documents - have a look at **Most popular** section and read

- PL/SQL user's guide and reference
- Application developer's guide - fundamentals

These documents describe *everything* you want to know about PL/SQL (at this stage of your knowledge).

Feel free to find similar documents related to database version you use.